# Does dropping/renaming an existing table that is created by EF Code First Approach and replacing that with a copy of that table will break the app?

Tags: database, entity-framework-6, database-migration

I'm not quite familiar with how DBAs handles the DB that is created by EF code first approach so I wanted to throw that question in. Just doing some analysis since we have a table that has 160 million records on it which has 4 years worth of data and we're limited with what we can do infrastructure-wise. So we were asked to archive and trim those records down of that table to one year... What was suggested by peers is to make a copy of that table (just structure no data), then backfill that with a year worth of data, once done, we'll do the swap by renaming the old table (then the new table to succeed the old ones). Seems like a decent plan to minimize the downtime, but I've realized that the table is handled by EF, is that going to be a problem since we keep a metadata of the DB in the Migration History table?

E.g. tables:

- TimeEntry -> contains 160 million records
- new_TimeEntry -> will get data transferred from TimeEntry (a year worth of data).

After the transfer:

- TimeEntry -> TimeEntry_Archived
- new_TimeEntry -> TimeEntry

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.

- Shut down the application that is using EF.
- Do what you want, add new tables and move data around and rename tables.
- When you are done, make sure the tables that EF knows about, are still in the same shape (same fields, relationsships, etc).
- Start the application that is using EF.

If the tables that are not known by EF, contain links to other tables and you want those maintained (when using the app implemented using EF), like cascading deletes and stuff like that, then you can not do what you want - then you must create your changes using an EF migration instead.